# Big-O of this algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, big-o

1. How can I describe the growth function in terms of n for the following algorithm?
2. What is the bounding function (the Big-O)? Is it O(n^3)?

---

```
for(i = 0 to n - 1)
{
    c = i + 1
    for(j = c to n)
    {
        arr[j] += arr[i];

        for(k = c to 0 step -1) // what does the keyword "step" mean?
        {
            arr[k] *= arr[j];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Step means that you are decrementing.  step 1, is assumed in the other for declarations.  Since this time we're counting down, step -1 is specified.

Comment: I answered [a three loop puzzle of this type here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13621550/a-puzzle-related-to-nested-loops) may be you find helpful

Comment: ohhh.  So that's why the "normal" i++ increment is not here.  The innermost for is k--?

Comment: yah, it's O(N^3)

Comment: So I have to find a closed formula for n?

Comment: @fallen  I just guessed it was o(n^3) because there are three for loops.  But, what is your logic?

Comment: @positiveimpact No not necessary try to draw the diagrams.. three loops doesn't means n^3 ..

Comment: 3 nested loops aren't enough to confirm it's O(N^3). let's do a simple math. There are n possible values of i. For each of the i s, there are (n-i) j's values and for every j there are another i values for k. so n * (n-i)*(i) operations in total. That roughly equals to n^3.

Comment: @positiveimpact *`c to 0 step -1`*  means every time it will run for one less then time suppose if `C = 4` then it will execute `4 3 2 1` times

Comment: Try to draw a tree like I have drawn in linked answer

Comment: @positiveimpact read this also: [Nested loops result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17019807/nested-loops-result?lq=1)

Comment: You should perhaps first read up about the differences between big-O, Omega, Theta and little-o. Big-O asks if a function is a upper bound. First there is no *the* bounding function, but the trick of big-O is that this is a whole family of functions. Then you should much more interested in a lower bound of the complexity (`Omega`) then in an upper bound `big-O`.

Comment: @Fallen, concerning big-O notation you are completely on the wrong track. For sure are 3 nested loops of length bounded by `n` enough to prove that there is a `C` such that `C x N` is an upper bound. You are arguing about a lower bound.

Comment: @JensGustedt: **....length bounded by n enough to...** is this condition present in my comment?

Comment: Brute force (albeit only to n=20):  The best fit I'm finding is loops^.36.  While that's a hair under n^3 it's close enough I would call it O(n^3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the rule in general :

for k nested loop you will have O(n^k) in the below case you will have O(n^3)

```
for(i = 0 to n - 1)
{
    c = i + 1
    for(j = c to n)
    {
        arr[j] += arr[i];

        for(k = c to 0 step -1) // what does the keyword "step" mean?
        {
            arr[k] *= arr[j];
        }
    }
}
```

For k loops next to each other you will have kxO(n) which comes back to O(n)

like below :

```
       for(k = c to 0 step -1) // what does the keyword "step" mean?
        {
            arr[k] *= arr[j];
        }
       for(k = c to 0 step -1) // what does the keyword "step" mean?
        {
            arr[k] *= arr[j];
        }
       for(k = c to 0 step -1) // what does the keyword "step" mean?
        {
            arr[k] *= arr[j];
        }
```

you have O(3xn) which is O(n)

You can also read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766939/finding-big-o-with-multiple-nested-loops

Comment: So the inner-most loop is O(n).  But, why does this mean that the whole algo. is O(n^3)?  I made a good guess, but I'm still not sure why.  I see your statement that it's O(n^3), but why is it n^k?

Comment: I don't believe that it is in fact O(n^3), this line of logic is ignoring the (c=i+1) line, which is very much diminishing the amount of work the inner loops need to do.  I am working on an answer.  I believe the tightest bounding function is actually O(n^2)

Comment: @ChrisCM: `for(int i=0;i<n;i++)for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++)for(int k=0;k<i;k++)` what should be the complexity for these three loops? ;-)

Comment: @Fallen: I'm not sure, but it is considerably less than for(i < n)for(j<n)for(k<n), which is n^3.

Comment: @Fallen it is `n x n/2 x n/2` I think but still considered as O(n^3)

Comment: actually you're right, it might be less than n^3, but big O is not calculated that way :) for an example `for(i=0;i<n;i++)for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)` needs actually (N*(N-1))/2 operations but still it's an O(N^2) algorithm

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766939/finding-big-o-with-multiple-nested-loops

Comment: Well, yes, but under this logic O(N^2) is also O(N!).  Why not just leave it at that?  On possible motivation in O-notation is to find the tightest bounding function.  There is a significantly tighter bounding function in this case than n^3.  Sometimes we want this tighter bound, sometimes we don't care.  But saying cut and dry, it's n^3 is incorrect.  If you're solving a problem like this you should at least be aware of this nuance, before ignoring it.

Comment: But I believe you're correct, the tightest bound is n^3/4, which is O(n^3)

Comment: I have the impression that you are trying to prove a lower bound. Big-O is looking for an upper bound. Stating that the algorithm is `O(n^3)` is trivial. `Omega(n^3)` is the difficult part.

Answer (score 3):

The question is about complexity but first, I was curious to know if I could compute the number of times this algorithm is doing the multiplication.

The 2 last inner loops are doing `c * (n - c)` iterations. This is equal to `nc - c²`.

The very first loop make the total number of iterations: `sum(c=1 to n) of (nc - c²)`

```
sum(c=1 to n) of (nc - c²)
= n*sum(c=1 to n) of c - sum(c=1 to n) of c²
= n*(n² + n) / 2 - (2n³ + 3n² + n) / 6
= (n³ - n) / 3
```

So the number of iterations is `(n³ - n) / 3` (answer to Q.1). And the complexity is then `O(n³)` (answer to Q.2).

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the already posted answers. However, I would like to present an alternative way of obtaining an asymptotic lower bound without having to obtain the closed form.

Consider only cases of `n>100`. For over `n/4` iterations, `c` is both greater than `n/3` and less than `2n/3`. Each of those iterations of the outer loop does at least `n/3` iterations of the middle loop, each of which does at least `n/3` iterations of the innermost loop. Thus the total number of innermost loop iterations is at least `(n/4) * (n/3) * (n/3)`.

The number of innermost loop iterations is bounded above by `n^3`, because each of the three nested loops does no more than `n` iterations.

A function that is bounded below by `(n^3)/36` and above by `n^3` is `Theta(n^3)`.

Answer (score 0):

It is clearly O(n^3), since it involves three loops. And for every loop you have, upper bound of times is 'n'(even the innermost loop), because it doesn't involve constant in any loop. Hence it is n^3 solution.

I have written a dummy count program to verify the same

```
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        int c = i + 1;
        for (int j = c; j < 100; j++) {
            for(int k= c; k >= 0; k--) {
                count ++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not every triply nested loop is O(n^3). The lower bound can effect the big-O a lot.

Comment: But this one doesn't involve constant for any loop. Before down voting please check, I have written a test program to find the upper bound too.

Comment: who is voting this down? this answer is correct. It *is* `O(n^3)`. That it is maybe also `O(n^2)` doesn't contradict this, `O(n^2)` is included in `O(n^3)`.

Comment: your calculation is correct. Downvote for this line, **It is clearly O(n^3), since it involves three loops.**

Comment: @Fallen As long as each of the three loops has an iteration count that is bounded above by a linear function of `n`, it must be `O(n^3)`. It may also be `O(n^2)`, or less, depending on the loop ranges. Big-O notation is only an upper bound.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: English is not my first language, sorry. but does **since it involves three loops.** look like having the phrase  **bounded by linear function of** `n` in any part of it to you? I don't want to argue anymore, thing is I can write a code with millions of for loops having complexity O(N) or even O(1).

Comment: @Fallen I agree that the complexity of a loop can vary. I'm stating a condition: **if** each of the three nested loops has iteration count bounded above by a linear function of n **then** the innermost code is executed O(n) times. Note that Big-O is only an upper bound. The constant function `f(n)=0` is `O(n^3)`.